# Two part question concerning AJAX / OData

Tags: ajax, json, odata

So in a custom .aspx form, I use an AJAX call to get current list item data.

1. When I copy "MYSITE" into my browser, I get a page that looks like a blank RSS feed. Any idea as to why this is? The code below (and obviously I didn't paste most of it) works great for what I need. But I'd like to access all my column names, etc. The few ways I've attempted reaching that information I've been denied in several different ways.
2. If I console.log($this) after the code below, I get my column names but they're chopped off. My question is: Why do some column names tack on the "OData_" prefix?

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     url: "MYSITE",
>     type: "GET",
>     headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
>     success: function(data){
>
>       $.each(data.d.results, function(index) { etc....
> ```

(I can't get the code block to format correctly here)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all fields information of list like this.

```
$.ajax({
url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/fields",
type: "GET",
headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data){
  console.log(data.d);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below will answer both your questions

You can use below url to get all your columns names.

https://yoursites/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('MyCustomList')/Fields?&$select=StaticName,Title

Below is sample response for your reference.

```
    {
    "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "https://yourdomain/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists(guid'7dcfd6ad-3126-43db-83d5-d712332a3')/Fields(guid'03e412384-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634')",
                "uri": "https://yourdomain/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists(guid'7dcfd6ad-3126-43db-83d5-d7e12378332a3')/Fields(guid'03e4123e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634')",
                "type": "SP.Field"
            },
            "StaticName": "ContentTypeId",
            "Title": "Content Type ID"
        },
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "https://yourdomain/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists(guid'7dcfd6123ad-3126-43db-83d5-d7e123332a3')/Fields(guid'fa5123e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247')",
                "uri": "https://yourdomain/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists(guid'7dcf123d6ad-3126-43db-83d5-d7e96123332a3')/Fields(guid'fa213e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247')",
                "type": "SP.FieldText"
            },
            "StaticName": "Title",
            "Title": "Title"
        },
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "https://yourdomain/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists(guid'7dcf123-3126-43db-83d5-d7e9678332a3')/Fields(guid'34ad123eb-75bd-4544-8c73-0e08330291fe')",
                "uri": "https://yourdomain/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists(guid'7dcf2136ad-3126-43db-83d5-d7e9678332a3')/Fields(guid'34ad1231eb-75bd-4544-8c73-0e08330291fe')",
                "type": "SP.FieldMultiLineText"
            },
            "StaticName": "_ModerationComments",
            "Title": "Approver Comments"
        }
    ]
}
```